# MIPS branch delay filler pattern: addiu $zero destination, with different numbered immediates, in empty functions?

Tags: assembly, mips, reverse-engineering

I'm working with some code written for a MIPS R3000A chip, and there's quite a few functions that seem completely useless to me... I'd like to verify they do what I think.

```
FNC_0000e3bc:                         # 
    jr      ra                        # 0000e3bc:03e00008   
    addiu       zero, zero, 0x0006    # 0000e3c0:24000006   
FNC_0000e3c4:                         # 
    jr      ra                        # 0000e3c4:03e00008   
    addiu       zero, zero, 0x0007    # 0000e3c8:24000007
```

I'm reading both of these as "return, and in the delay slot do nothing", is that correct?
If that's the case, is there any reason the `addiu`'s aren't just a `nop`? Or why these functions should be called at all?

What I find weird is there are these functions with the addiu number ranging from 4 to 0x21. Makes me want to think they do *something*, but I don't see how they would.

Either way, thanks for any input!

Edit: Well, I'm going to go with the "leftover from debugger" idea. It seems they all are called uniquely, so it fits. And this is for sound playback, so I really doubt they're doing op-code inspection (never know, but I doubt it).

Comment: perhaps it is for some debugger type activity, so they can tell where they are?

Comment: Maybe some part of the program inspects the opcodes. addiu zero, zero, 0x0006 is `0010 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110`

Answer (score 1):

What platform is this on? It is odd, but it does amount to the equivalent of `nop`, and yeah, I suspect either the debugger or some other part of the code uses it to do something funky in the executable at run-time (but hard to say without knowing the platform).

Comment: To be specific, it's a sound library written for the PlayStation 2's IOP processor. I did check to see if it was some funky type of syscall or something, but from what I see it's not.

Comment: You cannot have a `syscall` in a delay slot, so it's definitely not that. Interesting about the PS2 lib, since I was curious if this was console-related (me having had "grown up" on MIPS via PS1 development). Is what you posted above some auto-generated disassembly? Or is that the actual source code of the library? If the latter, then perhaps the developer used that in order to easily find parts of the code?

Comment: It's compiled, and being disassembled through ps2dis. I'm assuming it was originally C, since other executables in the same game were written in that (and it uses a version of printf).
Also, for what it's worth, this was probably compiled with a version of gcc from around 2002. (Date hardcoded in as debug is Apr 26 2002)

Comment: You can call `printf` even from assembly, so that alone isn't evidence of it being C-based. Without seeing the rest of the disassembly, it's hard to say from my experience whether it's C or pure asm, but I still think that those `addiu`s are for some kind of documentation or reference purposes since the typical `nop` on MIPS (which didn't otherwise have an explicit `nop` instruction) was `sll zero, zero, 0`.

Comment: That's what I'm going to go with, that they're related to a debugger. Either way, this does answer my question: these functions do absolutely nothing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh, heh, no problem. It's good to see 4 years of writing MIPS code on the PlayStation1 still being useful for someone in 2013. ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's what's called a branch delay slot. The instruction after a branch gets executed BEFORE the branch takes place. This is due to the way MIPS's instruction pipeline works. So in order to prevent that from happening you put a `nop` after the branch instruction.

Comment: Yes, but the question here is why those *aren't* all the same simple canonical `nop` like `sll $zero, $zero, 0`.  What's up with this differing "payload" in each `nop`?  Did a human or compiler do that, and why?